# Oracle on mac using VirtualBox with Windows 10 not working

Tags: windows, oracle, macos, virtualbox

I've been researching everywhere and couldn't solve the problem. I'm receiving the error:
**"Status: Failure-Test failed: IO Error: Got minus one from a read call."** when trying to connect to the Oracle server running on the VirtualBox in my Macbook.

What I did so far:

1. Installed Windows 10 x64 with default configuration on VirtualBox
2. Installed Oracle 11 XE 112 Win 64 on the Windows installed in the step #1
3. Installed SQL Developer 4.0.2.15 on my Macbook (OS X El Captain)
4. On VirtualBox, went to Network (Attached to NAT) and added port forwarding with:

   - host IP: 127.0.0.1
   - host port: 1521
   - guest ip: tried empty and after tried using my mac ip (192.168.2.68)
   - guest port: 1521
   - I also tried adding a Bridged second adapter. No luck.
5. Tested the Oracle local connection on Windows with the sql command line utility ("connect hr/hr") and could connect successfully.
6. Tested the Oracle listener on Windows using the lsnrctl utility ("status") and could see the "xe" listener active.
7. On my Mac, tried to connect using SQL Developer with every possible combination that I could imagine:

   - username/password: hr/hr
   - hostname: 127.0.0.1 / localhost / 10.0.2.15 (that's the virtual Windows ip)
   - service name: xe / xexdb / orcl
   - tried the same for SID.
   - Every time that I click in test, I receive the error mentioned before.
8. Disabled the firewall on the virtual Windows

Please, I researched everywhere here, google, oracle community, VirtualBox community and nothing. Thank you so much in advance.

ifconfig on my mac:

```
lo0: flags=8049<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING,MULTICAST> mtu 16384
    options=3<RXCSUM,TXCSUM>
    inet6 ::1 prefixlen 128 
    inet 127.0.0.1 netmask 0xff000000 
    inet6 fe80::1%lo0 prefixlen 64 scopeid 0x1 
    inet 127.94.0.2 netmask 0xff000000 
    inet 127.94.0.1 netmask 0xff000000 
    nd6 options=1<PERFORMNUD>
gif0: flags=8010<POINTOPOINT,MULTICAST> mtu 1280
stf0: flags=0<> mtu 1280
en0: flags=8863<UP,BROADCAST,SMART,RUNNING,SIMPLEX,MULTICAST> mtu 1500
    ether 54:26:96:e0:e7:57 
    inet6 fe80::5626:96ff:fee0:e757%en0 prefixlen 64 scopeid 0x4 
    inet 192.168.2.68 netmask 0xffffff00 broadcast 192.168.2.255
    nd6 options=1<PERFORMNUD>
    media: autoselect
    status: active
en1: flags=963<UP,BROADCAST,SMART,RUNNING,PROMISC,SIMPLEX> mtu 1500
    options=60<TSO4,TSO6>
    ether 32:00:1b:a0:70:e0 
    media: autoselect <full-duplex>
    status: inactive
en2: flags=963<UP,BROADCAST,SMART,RUNNING,PROMISC,SIMPLEX> mtu 1500
    options=60<TSO4,TSO6>
    ether 32:00:1b:a0:70:e1 
    media: autoselect <full-duplex>
    status: inactive
p2p0: flags=8843<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,SIMPLEX,MULTICAST> mtu 2304
    ether 06:26:96:e0:e7:57 
    media: autoselect
    status: inactive
awdl0: flags=8943<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,PROMISC,SIMPLEX,MULTICAST> mtu 1484
    ether 6a:0e:9b:1d:78:7b 
    inet6 fe80::680e:9bff:fe1d:787b%awdl0 prefixlen 64 scopeid 0x8 
    nd6 options=1<PERFORMNUD>
    media: autoselect
    status: active
bridge0: flags=8863<UP,BROADCAST,SMART,RUNNING,SIMPLEX,MULTICAST> mtu 1500
    options=63<RXCSUM,TXCSUM,TSO4,TSO6>
    ether 56:26:96:0e:29:00 
    Configuration:
        id 0:0:0:0:0:0 priority 0 hellotime 0 fwddelay 0
        maxage 0 holdcnt 0 proto stp maxaddr 100 timeout 1200
        root id 0:0:0:0:0:0 priority 0 ifcost 0 port 0
        ipfilter disabled flags 0x2
    member: en1 flags=3<LEARNING,DISCOVER>
            ifmaxaddr 0 port 5 priority 0 path cost 0
    member: en2 flags=3<LEARNING,DISCOVER>
            ifmaxaddr 0 port 6 priority 0 path cost 0
    nd6 options=1<PERFORMNUD>
    media: <unknown type>
    status: inactive
vboxnet0: flags=8943<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,PROMISC,SIMPLEX,MULTICAST> mtu 1500
    ether 0a:00:27:00:00:00 
    inet 192.168.56.1 netmask 0xffffff00 broadcast 192.168.56.255
```

ipconfig on the virtual Windows box:
[image]

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I couldn't find a solution installing Windows 10, but it worked super fine following the instructions of this [post](http://adfjsf.blogspot.com/2015/10/installing-oracle-xe-on-virtual-box-and.html)

Comment: Could you please edit this answer to describe the solution here instead of requiring somebody to click through the link?

Answer (score 0):

Your VirtualBox port forwarding configuration is incorrect, guest IP should be `10.0.2.15`, not your host IP address. After that, you should be able to connect through `127.0.0.1:1521` on your host OS.

Comment: Unfortunately I tried this but it's appearing the same error. Looks like SQLDeveloper keeps trying to connect for a while and after gives up.

Comment: Just tried again following this [link](http://www.thatjeffsmith.com/archive/2014/03/connecting-to-oracle-from-your-host-to-a-virtualbox-oel-guest/) but no luck.  :(